# Cassandra Materialized Views Not updating

Tags: cassandra, nosql, datastax, data-recovery, data-import

I had created table1 and a view on top of table1_vies. When I inserted the data through code or copy command its absolutely working fine. But I had faced a situation where my Cassandra went down so recovered the data from my snapshot. When I'm restoring the data through snapshot the views are not automatically updated(used nodetool refresh)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this thread from the Cassandra User Forums. It states that if you determine a view is out of sync, the only way to fix is to drop and recreate the view.

https://www.mail-archive.com/user@cassandra.apache.org/msg54073.html